# How to build a Terminal like iPad App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, terminal

I want to build a Terminal like App for the iPad/iPhone. 
I only need to build the GUI part, meaning the prompt, the cursor (including the correct positioning), black background, scrolling behavior, etc.

It only should look and behave like a Terminal (like e.g. 'Prompt', 'Get Console', 'iSSH', 'mobileterminal' or any of the SSH apps but w/o the system access). The data comes from an web service and not form any device internal place. I don't want to 'root around' in the device, no jailbreak required, I just want to build the GUI and the behavior.

Does anybody have some tips or sample code for me. I'm wondering how I can accomplish the look and feel and the behavior. Which controls/View classes fits best, where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, [MobileTerminal](http://code.google.com/p/mobileterminal/) is probably what you're looking for. This project is open-source and you can start of it. AFAIK now it runs only on jailbroken devices, but you can definitely cut out only the terminal emulation (& screen manipulation, handling input and output, ...) and build your project on it.

Building a terminal from scratch is quite complicated and complex, so I suggest you start with this or some other open source project.

I am not aware of any ready-to-use component, so you'll probably have to put some work into integrating the terminal into your app.

Comment: Ok, thanks kuba. Since no one else had a tipp, I give it a try.